# Plotting data from the file kills GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I try to draw a graph from the data I have in the file. For example, a set of data with several chart points is no problem and it is drawn. However, the amount of data I have to draw is constantly growing and it is currently about 15000 points. When I try to load and draw them, the application interface crashes. My code is below. The data file is here: [testdata.txt](https://pastebin.com/VdxC51bf) Could you please tell me how to deal with it?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 



class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        title = "Wykresy"

        self.setWindowTitle(title)

        # a figure instance to plot on 
        self.figure = plt.figure() 
   
        # this is the Canvas Widget that  
        # displays the 'figure'it takes the 
        # 'figure' instance as a parameter to __init__ 
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure) 
   
        # this is the Navigation widget 
        # it takes the Canvas widget and a parent 
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self) 
   
        # Just some button connected to 'plot' method 
        self.button = QPushButton('Plot') 
           
        # adding action to the button 
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.plot) 
   
        # creating a Vertical Box layout 
        layout = QVBoxLayout() 
           
        # adding tool bar to the layout 
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar) 
           
        # adding canvas to the layout 
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas) 
           
        # adding push button to the layout 
        layout.addWidget(self.button) 
           
        # setting layout to the main window 
        self.setLayout(layout) 


        self.showMaximized()

        


    def plot(self):
        with open('testdata.txt') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            x = [line.split('\t')[0] for line in lines]
            y = [line.split('\t')[1] for line in lines]
    

        # clearing old figure 
        self.figure.clear() 
   
        # create an axis 
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111) 

        # plot data
        ax.plot(x, y, c = 'r', label = 'temperature')
        
        self.figure.autofmt_xdate()
        
        # refresh canvas 
        self.canvas.draw() 

# driver code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    # loop 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main bottleneck seems to be the `autofmt_xdate()` call, which adds a date label for *every one* of those 15k points. This happens because your x labels aren't actually dates; as far as pyplot is concerned, they're just arbitrary strings, so it doesn't know which ones to keep and which ones to throw away. Something similar is happening for the y labels too.

To parse x into `datetime` objects and y into `float`s:

```
from datetime import datetime

...
        x = [datetime.strptime(line.split('\t')[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for line in lines]
        y = [float(line.split('\t')[1]) for line in lines]
```

Now I get a single tick per hour on the x axis, and one per 2.5 degrees on the y axis. Rendering is nearly instantaneous.

You should also consider downsampling your data before trying to plot it. 15000 points is way more than fits in the horizontal resolution of a typical computer screen anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Thomas' answer, you could use `pandas` to read the file, which may be faster than looping through the content.

```
(...)
def plot(self):
    df = pd.read_csv('testdata.txt', sep='\t', header=None, parse_dates=[0])
    (...)
    # plot data
    ax.plot(df[0], df[1], c='r', label='temperature')
```